# Remove \n from string python 3.6

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, replace, nslookup

I am trying to remove the \n characters from the output of a nslookup. While this seems like a simple task and there are many posts about filtering \n they do not seem to work for me. Code works perfectly in Python 2.7 however it does not in 3.6

```
mx = str(subprocess.check_output(('nslookup -type=mx ' + "test.nl"), shell=True))

clean = re.sub(r"\n", " ", mx)
clean2 = mx.replace("\n", " ")

print(clean)
print(clean2)
```

Output

```
\nNon-authoritative answer:\ntest.nl\tmail exchanger
```

Wanted result

```
 Non-authoritative answer: test.nl\tmail exchanger
```

Neither of these work, however when I remove the '\' it filters the 'n' perfectly. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong? Or how I can achieve the wanted result?

ps: Well aware this could be a duplicate and I'm just making a dumb mistake, However the solutions given in similar posts do not work for me.

Comment: str.replace("\n", " ") works for me... can't really reproduce. Can you provide the exact content of mx?

Comment: Show print(mx), print(type(mx)), becase simple replace works perfectly

Comment: in python2.7 works perfect your code :/

Comment: `re.sub(r"\n", " ", "foo\nbar")` also works fine in Python 3. Result: `'foo bar'`

Comment: @inye what.. your absolutely right, it does work in python 2.7, however in 3.6.5 it does not :o

Comment: @anothernode It works fine when I use a string like you did, however not when I convert the output like in the example

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you use \n for replacing, that is interpreted as a line break by python or as line feed character by Regex.

You can use a raw string so Python won't parse the \n:

```
clean = mx.replace(r"\n", " ")
```

Or you can escape the symbol:

```
clean = mx.replace("\\n", " ")
```